# Cannot read point values from BACnet device

Tags: python, bacnet

I am trying to read values from my BACnet device. I followed the example [Error reading point values from BACnet device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491437/error-reading-point-values-from-bacnet-device).

However, I get the following output:

```
2021-12-06 17:10:27,718 - INFO    | BAC0 started
2021-12-06 17:10:27,718 - INFO    | Registered as Simple BACnet/IP App
2021-12-06 17:10:27,740 - INFO    | Update Local COV Task started
2021-12-06 17:10:27,740 - INFO    | Changing device state to DeviceDisconnected'>
2021-12-06 17:10:37,762 - WARNING | Error connecting: APDU Abort Reason : Timeout
2021-12-06 17:10:37,763 - WARNING | Offline: provide database name to load stored data.
2021-12-06 17:10:37,764 - WARNING | Ex. controller.connect(db = 'backup')
```

It seems the BAC0.device command is not able to create a device given the parameters and fetch its points.

```
bacnet = BAC0.lite()
fx = BAC0.device(device_ipaddr, device_instance, bacnet, object_list='obj_list')

for name in fx.points_name:
    if fx[name].units:
        val = '{:>10.2f}'.format(fx[name].lastValue)
        units = fx[name].units
    else:
        units = '({})'.format(fx[name].properties.units_state)
        val = '{:>10}'.format(fx[name].lastValue)
        print('{:<20} : {} {:<10}'.format(fx[name].properties.name, val, units))
```

Comment: What is `device_ipaddr` and `device_insance`? Are you trying to read Objects and Properties of a remote BACnet/IP server? Please provide some more details.

Comment: Timeout means : I can't reach the device. Be sure you define your bacnet network (BAC0.lite()) using the IP that can reach the device. For example, if connecting by VPN, use the IP of your machine VPN interface.

Comment: For the benefit of open/cross-cutting collaboration - for others in the same conundrum, looks like this might have already been solved on the BAC0 project site by Christian:  https://github.com/ChristianTremblay/BAC0/issues/146

Comment: Yes, it addresses it. Thank you.